# Not Able To PULL EOS Image From Docker

Tags: voting, cleos, docker

I'm trying to use the CLEOS command line to vote, but as I follow the tutorial on developers.eos.io I'm running into problems pulling the Docker image.

So I've installed Docker on a fresh installation using Linux Mint Cinnamon. When I run **docker --version** it responds with **Docker version 1.13.1 build..** then it shows a short alpha-numeric build code showing that it's installed.

So then I run **docker pull eosio/eos-dev** and it's coming back with an error saying **Warning: failed to get default registry endpoint from daemon**

Is this happening because the Mainnet hasn't be validated and opened to the public yet? If anyone can help me with this so I can vote using CLEOS, I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Two suggestions:

1) Try to run it with admin privileges

```
sudo docker pull ...
```

2) If that still fails, clean your docker images/volumes/containers. Afterwards you can try the production image. With

```
sudo docker pull eosio/eos
```

---

**Edit:**

Seems that your docker daemon is not running.

Try to run

```
dockerd
```

Maybe use some of the answers from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43058226/4326433)

Comment: Actually I just figured out a workaround, I skipped to the next step and simply ran the startup for the EOSIO node and it worked! It said it was unable to find the image locally, so it automatically started pulling it from eosio/eos-dev. Then I ran **sudo docker logs --tail 10 eosio** and it began giving me the produced blocks. I also ran http://localhost:8888/v1/chain/get_info and I got a similar readout to what the tutorial said I'd get! So it looks like I have a node running locally on my Linux!! Now CLEOS is giving me problems, so I have to figure that out but I'm going to take a break

Comment: Nice to hear. Then good luck with that.